# How to access private pointed classes

Tags: c++

Im trying to learn this linkedList Stack ADT stuff and I initialized null head and tryed to add a node to that. But since "Node* head" is private, I cant access it. I know i have to change its type specifier but I have a homework that needs to be kept private. Also when i do that public, i cant make any changes and i got exceptionthrow error that says is null. Here is the code(codes are copied from lecture slides, i only added main):

```
#include <iostream>

using namespace std;

class Node {
public:
    Node(int);
    int data;
    Node* next;
};

Node::Node(int x){
    data = x;
}

class LinkedList {
public:
    LinkedList();
    void insert(Node*, int);
    void printList();
    ~LinkedList();
private:
    Node* head;
};

LinkedList::LinkedList() {
    head = 0;
}

void LinkedList::printList() {
    Node* n = head;
    while (n != 0) {
        cout << n->data;
        n = n->next;
    }
}

void LinkedList::insert(Node* current, int X) {
    Node* xNode = new Node(X);
    xNode->next = current->next;
    current->next = xNode;
}

LinkedList::~LinkedList() {
    Node* dNode = head;
    while (dNode != 0) {
        head = head->next;
        delete dNode;
        dNode = head;
    }
}

int main() {
    LinkedList *list = new LinkedList();
    list->insert(//whatShouldIdoHere, 5);
    list->printList();

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Note: You should try to avoid using `new` where possible to keep manual memory management to a bare minimum. This is a bit tricky with nodes in a linked list ([Doable](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=JfmTagWcqoE), but outside the scope of this question) but the linked list itself probably shouldn't be dynamically allocated. That means `LinkedList *list = new LinkedList();` should probably be `LinkedList list;` This will give you a linked list that is Automatically allocated and will be destroyed for you as soon as `main` ends.

Comment: This is also a good time to bring [The Rule of Three and its friends Five and Zero](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/rule_of_three) to your attention. As written `LinkedList` cannot be copied (and it's pretty easy to accidentally copy something) without having two `LinkedList` pointing at the same list of nodes. Sooner or later one of the lists will go out of scope, the destructor will fire, and the linked nodes for BOTH copies will be destroyed, turning the surviving `LinkedList` into a timebomb.

Answer (score 1):

Anything outside of `LinkedList` shouldn't have any idea what a `Node` is. If you want to insert something into a list, you should really only be giving the value you're going to insert. The LinkedList class itself should do the work to figure out where things actually need to be placed.

So instead, you should have some publicly facing function that just takes a value, like:

```
void LinkedList::push_front(int X) {
    insert(head, X); //Insert into the front of the list
}
```

(Also don't forget the edge case in `insert` where you'll need to update the value of `head`!!)

Comment: [Iterators](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Iterator) are a common solution to the "How do I hide the node form the user?" problem. The user gets an iterator that they can use to refer to the data at a node and the position within the list without knowing anything about the node or the internal structure of the list.